# HERE Maps Find Marker by Id issues

Tags: javascript, here-api

Using [Here Maps](https://developer.here.com/documentation) I have set up a map with a group of markers placed on the map.

I want to be able to call attention to a certain marker if a corresponding table row is clicked elsewhere on the page.  In the data for that table I have the current id of the marker related to that row when that marker was placed `devices[arrIdx].here_id = marker.getId();`.  I can't find any documentation on how to get the marker in question based on that id later so I can manipulate the map (center on marker) and that marker (ie bring to front over other markers) if the row is clicked on in the table.  Any Help would be great.

Comment: Updated the answer as I noticed I originally misunderstood what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to retrieve all map objects, iterate over those objects, and lookup their id if the object is an instance of H.map.Marker:

```
// retrieve all map objects
const mapObjects = map.getObjects();

// iterate
for (i = 0; i < mapObjects.length; i++) {
  if (mapObjects[i] instanceof H.map.Marker) {
    // lookup the id
  }
}
```

To bring the relevant marker to front you'll have to play with the `setZIndex(zIndex)` method on the set of markers.